# How to highlight grep result

Tags: grep

I use this code:

```
grep -niE smith /home/user/docs/*
```

to get a result as this:

```
/home/user/docs/bils.pdf:120$:Smith
```

I need to colorize just "120$", nothing else

It's possible? thanks

Comment: Does results have some specific format?

Comment: they don't, just a string on Terminal as I have posted before

Comment: Do all of them has a piece of `%d$`?

Comment: what means? all I can get are:

/home/user/docs/bils.pdf:120$:Smith

/home/user/docs/bils.pdf:3310$:Gregory
and so on

Comment: Append `| grep --color=always '120$'`?

Comment: @Cyrus `120$` is not a fixed string for all outputs. It may be other values as mentioned in the comments, like this`3310$`.

Comment: Are you searching for the files' names? not the content of the files?

Answer (score 0):

This grep command may help you:

```bash
(amirreza@localhost:~) > echo "/home/user/docs/bils.pdf:120$:Smith" | grep -oP '(?<=:)[0-9]+[\\$]+(?=:)'
120$
(amirreza@localhost:~) > echo "/home/user/docs/bils.pdf:3310$:Gregory" | grep -oP '(?<=:)[0-9]+[\\$]+(?=:)'
3310$
```

So you can pipe the result of you own command to the above grep:

```bash
ls /home/user/docs/ -1 | grep -niE smith |  grep -P '(?<=:)[0-9]+[\\$]+(?=:)'
```

```bash
(amirreza@localhost:~) > ls /home/user/docs/ -1 | grep -niE smith |  grep -P '(?<=:)[0-9]+[\\$]+(?=:)'
1:bils.pdf:10$:Smith  # 10$ is colorized now
```

Comment: Your code seems no to work but I think to give you some bad info. 
I have some files filled as this:


    `contract:area3:John:Smith:120$:employer   
    freelance:area2:Alice:Still:830$:manager`


All I need is to run "grep -niE WorkerName /home/user/docs/*" (or something) in order to get a result as this one:


`/home/user/docs/bils.pdf:contract:area3:John:Smith:*120$*:employer` (highlighted or colored)

Answer (score 0):

On my WSL, it is that standard that an alias is created for this:

```
alias grep='grep -a --color=auto'
```

So, if you add `--color=auto` to your `grep` command, that should work.

Comment: The question is how to colorize the specific part of the output. This switch will colorize the whole output.

Comment: I don't understand how to edit 

`grep -niE smith /home/user/docs/*`

to get

`/home/user/docs/bils.pdf:120$:Smith`

where 120$ part only is highlighted (or colored)

Comment: @Lilia I edited my answer, it's now what you want. You should use `grep` without `-o` switch.

Answer (score 0):

Match the account, then match anything that looks like a price:

```
grep -niE 'smith' /home/user/docs/* | grep --color '[0-9]*\$'
```